# Chunks of async_generator

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

I can get chunks of an iterator doing as follow:

```
def get_chunks_it(l, n):
    """ Chunks an iterator `l` in size `n`
    Args:
        l (Iterator[Any]): an iterator
        n (int): size of
    Returns:
        Generator[Any]
    """
    iterator = iter(l)
    for first in iterator:
        yield itertools.chain([first], itertools.islice(iterator, n - 1))
```

Now let's say I have an asynchronous generator (python 3.6):

```
async def generator():
    for i in range(0, 10):
        yield i
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
```

How could I get chunks (let's say of size 3 that would yield [0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [9]) of the resulting `async_generator` so that I could write:

```
async for chunk in get_chunk_it_async(generator(), 3):
    print(chunk)
```

Comment: What is going to be the async generator here? Is it `l`? If so, then you'll have to work around the lack of an `aiter()` function (it won't be available [until Python 3.7](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0525/#aiter-and-anext-builtins), but we can work around that if you make certain assumptions).

Comment: Well, that certainly was interesting, because everything you use needs to have an async equivalent, which were not available (so I wrote them from scratch).

Comment: @MartijnPieters The [aiostream](http://pythonhosted.org/aiostream/presentation.html) library provides asynchronous equivalents to [iter](http://pythonhosted.org/aiostream/utilities.html#aiostream.aiter_utils.aiter), [chain](http://pythonhosted.org/aiostream/operators.html#aiostream.stream.chain), [islice](http://pythonhosted.org/aiostream/operators.html#aiostream.stream.getitem), [etc](http://pythonhosted.org/aiostream/presentation.html#module-aiostream.stream).

Comment: @Vincent: interesting, noted! Those are a little heavier-weight, but I may well reach for those objects in future for other needs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is slightly complicated by the [lack of an `aiter()` function](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0525/#aiter-and-anext-builtins) in Python 3.6 (it'll be added in 3.7 once returning an awaitable from `__aiter__` is properly deprecated). There are no async versions of `itertools` objects yet either.

Define your own:

```
try:
    aiter
except NameError:
    # not yet a built-in, define our own shim for now
    from inspect import iscoroutinefunction as _isasync
    def aiter(ob, _isasync=_isasync):
        obtype = type(ob)  # magic methods are looked up on the type
        if not hasattr(obtype, '__aiter__'):
            raise TypeError(f'{obtype.__name__!r} object is not async iterable')
        async_iter = obtype.__aiter__(ob)
        if _isasync(async_iter):
            # PEP 492 allowed for __aiter__ to be a coroutine, but 525 reverses this again
            raise TypeError(f'{obtype.__name__!r} object is not async iterable')
        return async_iter
    del _isasync
```

Next, you need to define async `islice` and `chain` objects:

```
class achain():
    """Chain over multiple async iterators"""
    def __init__(self, *async_iterables):
        self._source = iter(async_iterables)
        self._active = None
    def __aiter__(self):
        return self
    async def __anext__(self):
        if self._source is None:
            # we are all done, nothing more to produce
            raise StopAsyncIteration
        if self._active is None:
            # get next async iterable to loop over
            ait = next(self._source, None)
            if ait is None:
                # we are all done, nothing more to produce
                self._source = None
                raise StopAsyncIteration
            self._active = aiter(ait)
        try:
            return await type(ait).__anext__(ait)
        except StopAsyncIteration:
            # exhausted, recurse
            self._active = None
            return await self.__anext__()

class aslice():
    """Slice an async iterator"""
    def __init__(self, ait, start, stop=None, step=1):
        if stop is None:
            start, stop = 0, start
        self._ait = ait
        self._next, self._stop, self._step = start, stop, step
        self._cnt = 0
    def __aiter__(self):
        return self
    async def __anext__(self):
        ait, stop = self._ait, self._stop
        if ait is None:
            raise StopAsyncIteration
        anext = type(ait).__anext__
        while self._cnt < self._next:
            try:
                await anext(ait)
            except StopAsyncIteration:
                self._ait = None
                raise
            self._cnt += 1
        if stop is not None and self._cnt >= stop:
            self._ait = None
            raise StopAsyncIteration
        try:
            item = await anext(ait)
        except StopAsyncIteration:
            self._ait = None
            raise
        self._cnt += 1
        self._next += self._step
        return item
```

With those in place, simply add `async` in the right places:

```
async def get_chunks_it(l, n):
    """ Chunks an async iterator `l` in size `n`
    Args:
        l (Iterator[Any]): an iterator
        n (int): size of
    Returns:
        Generator[Any]
    """
    iterator = aiter(l)
    async for first in iterator:
        async def afirst():
            yield first
        yield achain(afirst, aslice(iterator, n - 1))
```

Comment: Shouldn't `return first` be `yield first`?

Comment: @Vincent: well spotted! yes, it should be.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [aiostream.stream.chunks](http://aiostream.readthedocs.io/en/latest/operators.html#aiostream.stream.chunks):

```
from aiostream import stream

async def main():
    async for x in stream.chunks(generator(), 3):
        print(x)
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 2]
[3, 4, 5]
[6, 7, 8]
[9]
```

See the [project page](https://github.com/vxgmichel/aiostream) and the [documentation](http://aiostream.readthedocs.io) for further information.

<sub>Disclaimer: I am the project maintainer.</sub>

Comment: This does transform each chunk into a list (the OP's code produces an iterator for each chunk, my answer yields async iterators).

Comment: @MartijnPieters True, but yielding async iterators is quite tricky. What happens if the user code does not consume all the elements of an iterator before it asks for the next one? I thought it was less error-prone to yield a list, but I guess this might change in the future.

Comment: This library looks neat, but you should add a note that it uses GPL license.

Comment: @Rotareti Thanks, I added a link to the project page so it's easier to find license information.

Answer (score 1):

## For `python3.10+`

Without any external libraries. Typehinted.

```py
from typing import AsyncIterator, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")


async def async_chunks(
    async_iterator: AsyncIterator[T],
    size: int,
) -> AsyncIterator[list[T]]:
    """Generate chunks from an asynchronous sequence.

    Chunks are lists consists of original ``T`` elements.
    The chunk can't contain more than ``size`` elements.
    The last chunk might contain less than ``size`` elements, 
    but can't be empty.
    """
    finished = False

    while not finished:
        results: list[T] = []

        for _ in range(size):
            try:
                result = await anext(async_iterator)
            except StopAsyncIteration:
                finished = True
            else:
                results.append(result)

        if results:
            yield results
```

## For older python versions

Replace

```py
await anext(async_iterator)
```

with

```py
await async_iterator.__anext__()
```